# Custom psobject truncating the results that are added using add-member

Tags: windows, powershell, failovercluster, windows-clustering

I have two clusters, cluster1 with 5 nodes and cluster2 with 4 nodes. With below script the cluster1 output is getting truncated. How to address this problem?

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $temp = @()
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> foreach($i in @('cluster1','cluster2')){
>> $pso = New-Object -TypeName psobject
>> $cluster = Get-Cluster $i | select name
>> $cluster_nodes = Get-ClusterNode -Cluster $cluster.Name | select name
>> $pso | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Cluster' -Value $cluster.Name
>> $pso | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Cluster_nodes' -Value $cluster_nodes.name
>> $temp += $pso
>> }
```

Output:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $temp

Cluster         Cluster_nodes
-------         -------------
cluster1        {node1, node2, node3, node4...}
cluster2        {node1, node2, node3, node4}
```

Comment: Does piping the output to `| Format-Table -AutoSize` fix the issue?

Comment: no, tried that.

Comment: `$formatenumerationlimit` controls this. The default value is 4. You can set it to -1 for unlimited or something else that fits your collection sizes.

Comment: @AdminOfThings Sonofagun!  I've been trying to figure that one out for a LONG time.  I just finished writing up a long rant about how I couldn't get it to display more than 4 items and posting it as an "answer" (which I've since deleted... O.o) when I saw your comment.  Thanks a million and a half!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AdminOfThings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11025476/adminofthings) provided the crucial pointer in a comment on the question:

[**Preference variable `$FormatEnumerationLimit`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#formatenumerationlimit) controls how many elements of a *collection-valued* property to display in formatted output.

E.g, `$FormatEnumerationLimit = 2; [pscustomobject] @{ prop = 1, 2, 3 }` prints (at most) 2 elements from `.prop`'s value and hints at the existence of more with `...`; e.g., `{1, 2...}`).

- The **default value is `4`**, but you can set it to an arbitrary positive value.
- **`-1`** places **no limit** on how many values are displayed, but note that with *tabular* output (implicit or explicit `Format-Table`) the *column width* may still truncate the value list.

  - Pipe to `Format-List` to ensure that *all* values are shown.

**Caveat**: Due to a **bug** as of PowerShell [Core] 7.0, setting `$FormatEnumerationLimit` is only effective in the *global* scope - see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/888).

- As a **workaround** in scripts, modify the *global* copy, `$global:FormatEnumerationLimit`, *temporarily* (restore it to the original value before exiting the script).